# Are there any classes that implement javax.persistence.Parameter<T>?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm using named queries to fetch entities from a database using JPA and Hibernate and I came across something that was puzzling me: how come there a no default implementations of the `javax.persistence.Parameter` interface?

I was rather impressed by how `@StaticMetamodel` is used by CriteriaBuilder in JPA2 meaning that I get Type safety and don't have to mess around with setting string for names. I wanted to apply something similar to some of the JPA1 EJB's that I'm currently working on:

```
Dealergroup_.class:
public Dealergroup_ 
{
  public Parameter<Integer> id  = new ParameterImpl<Integer>("id");
  /// etc...
}

DealergroupFacade.class:
// ...
public Dealergroup fetch(Integer id)
{
  TypedQuery<Dealergroup> query = em.createNamedQuery("Dealergroup.fetchById", Dealergroup.class);
  query.setParameter(Dealergroup_.id, query);
  return query.getSingleResult();
}
// ...
```

I was surprised to find that there were no implementations of the Parameter interface - of course, I could easily implement it myself by their absence makes me suspicious that it may be a mistake to be using it in this way?

Should I be implementing Parameter? Any ideas why there isn't a readily available implementation and why I can't find many (any, really) examples of its use?

Answer (score 1):

That is an interface that a JPA implementation will implement with their implementation of Criteria "ParameterExpression" (which extends Parameter), using their own implementation class. A user goes via `CriteriaBuilder.parameter()` to get hold of one, or via `Query.getParameter()` when one is defined by traditional means in the query

Comment: They wouldn't be static though, would they?

Comment: The JPA2 javadocs are public http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html